# Creating Decision Tree for Simple Game

Tags: python

I am currently a new student learning python. This is my first real experience doing much computer coding. For my project I must create a fill in the blank quiz with three different levels of difficulty. Once the user chooses a difficulty the game should print a different paragraph based on the difficulty. Each section of the game works fine but I am having trouble creating the "difficulty chooser." No matter the difficulty I choose, the game rolls through the easy, medium, and the hard level in order and then crashes.

Below I have included the introductory text and the difficulty chooser. I would love some help. I am sure there are really obvious things I don't see. Thank you!

```
    def introduction():
        print '''Welcome to Kevin's European Geography Quizzes. 
        Test your knowledge of European geography. \n'''
        difficulty = raw_input('''Do you want to play an easy, medium, or hard game? 
        Please type the number 1 for easy, 2 for medium, or 3 for hard.\n''' )
        game_chooser(difficulty)

    def game_chooser(difficulty):
        cursor = 0
        difficulty_choice = [easy_game(), medium_game(), hard_game()]
 #each element of the above list links to a procedure and starts one of the 
 #mini-games.
        while cursor < len(difficulty_choice):
            if difficulty != cursor:
                cursor += 1
            else: 
                difficulty_choice[cursor]
                break
```

Comment: You need a conditional to check the input. Its hard to give you a good answer with what you have shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a conditional for the input.

```python
if difficulty == 'easy':
    print("here is an easy game")
elif difficulty == 'medium':
    print('here is a medium game')
elif difficulty == 'hard':
    print('here is hard')
else:
    print('Please enter valid input (easy, medium, hard)')
```

Under each if statement put your game code.

Comment: This solved it. I didn't know about elif. I had previously tried something similar to this code block except with three if statements in a row. It did not work as intended.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can do with `if else` if you only want to print something but if you have separate code block for each level then define a function for each level and use this pattern :

You can define the function blocks and call them basis on user input something like:

```
    # define the function blocks
    def hard():
        print ("Hard mode code goes here.\n")

    def medium():
        print ("medium mode code goes here\n")

    def easy():
        print ("easy mode code goes here\n")

    def lazy():
        print ("i don't want to play\n")

    # Now map the function to user input
    difficulty_choice = {0 : hard,
               1 : medium,
               4 : lazy,
               9 : easy,

    }
    user_input=int(input("which mode do you want to choose : \n press 0 for hard \n press 1 for medium \n press 4 for lazy \n press 9 for easy "))
    difficulty_choice[user_input]()
```

Then invocation of function block will be:

```
    difficulty_choice[num]()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code goes through all the difficulties is because of this line:

```
difficulty_choice = [easy_game(), medium_game(), hard_game()]
```

When Python sees something like `easy_game()`, it calls the `easy_game` function and replaces it with the result. You don't want to call the function yet though, so you can take off the parenthesis to store just the function instead:

```
difficulty_choice = [easy_game, medium_game, hard_game]
```

This will mean you have to call the function after you take it out of the array.

As for the crash, when you use `raw_input()` you get a string back. That means when you type in the `1` to decide for an easy game, you get the character `1`, which is represented by the number `49`. That's why your code goes through everything and crashes: Your `1` is really a `49`. In fact, if you type `1 < '1'` into the interpreter, you'll get `True` back.

To fix that, you can pass the result of `raw_input()` to the `int()` function, which will parse it and give you the proper integer (or throw an exception if it can't be parsed). The last line of `introduction` would then look like `game_chooser(int(difficulty))`.

You could also skip most of the code of `game_chooser` by just indexing into the array (that's what they're for, after all):

```
def game_chooser(difficulty):
    # the lack of parens here means you get the function itself, not what it returns
    difficulty_choice = [easy_game, medium_game, hard_game]

    #each element of the above list links to a procedure and starts one of the 
    #mini-games. 

    # note the parens to actually call the retrieved function now
    difficulty_choice[difficulty]()
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. They answer a lot of questions that were in my head concerning why the game kept running through every difficulty.

Comment: No problem. I think it's useful to get the right mental model so you understand what your code is doing, especially if you're trying to make a career out of it. You'll go much further (and much faster) if you understand what's happening instead of always guessing. Welcome to programming, and good luck. =)